# Handlebars each helper not working

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

I am trying to get the `#each` working for the following template. Have been trying for a while and couldn't get it to work. Not sure what I am missing.

```
 <script>
        $(function () {
            var endpoint = "/" + "order/activeholdreasons";
            $.get(endpoint, function (data) {
                renderHoldReaonsTemplate(data);
            });

            $("#adminHoldModalHeading").text(adminHoldModalHeadingText);   
        });

        function renderHoldReaonsTemplate(holdReasons) {
            var template = $("#holdReasonsTemplate").html();
            var compiled = Handlebars.compile(template);
            var rendered = compiled({ holdReasons: holdReasons, language: window.language });
            $("#holdReasonsContainer").html(rendered);
            console.log(rendered);
            console.log(template);
            }
    </script>

    <script id="holdReasonsTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        {{#each holdReasons}}
        <div class="row">
            <input type="radio" value="{{id}}" /><label>{{text}}</label>
        </div>
        {{/each}}
    </script>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're getting values back in `holdReasons`?

Comment: @cwallenpoole yes I am.

Comment: Can you provide it above? It looks like you're calling things right.

Comment: It is basically a json array of id and text. If I pass single object it works with out each. Looks like it doesnt complie.